# Using <ui:repeat><h:inputText> for varStatus and index error

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

When i use index with outputText, anything is OK.

```
<ui:repeat id="topTenGrd" var="dream" value="#{dreamModifyBean.topDreams}" varStatus="status">
    <h:outputText class="dream-title uppercase" value="#{status.index}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

But i change outputText -> inputText then when click any button on screen , the error PropertyNoWritableException occured.

```
<ui:repeat id="topTenGrd" var="dream" value="#{dreamModifyBean.topDreams}" varStatus="status">
    <h:inputText class="dream-title uppercase" value="#{status.index}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you using Richfaces?

Comment: Refere this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575421/propertynotwritableexception-illegal-syntax-for-set-operation-error-when-sett

Comment: @venkatraj : tks for comment. I don't use Rickfaces.

Comment: Okay, then refer the above link, it will help you to resolve your issue. If you use h:inputText, then must need getter and setter. in your program you did't use encapsulation. you directly getting values for h:inputText from the ui:repeat varStatus.

Comment: You cannot SET the varStatus index property... That is just not how it should be used

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**JAVA:**

```
String indexs[] = new String[10]; // Need encaptulation
```

**UI:**

```
<ui:repeat id="topTenGrd" var="dream" value="#{dreamModifyBean.indexs}" varStatus="status">
    <h:inputText class="dream-title uppercase" value="#{dream}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: I _think_ that will throw an error of some kind as well... `value="{dreamModifyBean.indexs[status.index]}"` is what should be used in case of Strings. See the duplicate Q/A